# How to use a specific font from a font family

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, custom-font, textstyle

so, I'm using android studio, and in my pubspec, I've added say poppins-regular, poppins-bold, poppin-italics, poppins-semiBold, all under the same family:poppins and in different parts of my code, I need to use them separately, how do I use a particular one instead of just mentioning the family and it decides which one to use for me

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: const [
            Text(
              'How\'s it work',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 40,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Just sample code',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

say in the first text I want it to be poppins-semibold and in the second Poppins-italics how do I specify that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextStyle` has several properties that you can use. In your case, semibold means FontWeight being 600 and italic is simply italic.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: const [
            Text(
              'Semibold',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 40,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Italic',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 40,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```